# Outlook 2010 VSTO Change Attachment Size on Filename

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, add-in, mapi

Hello I am writing a Outlook 2010 addin and I basically I need to manipulate the size of the attachment being show in the OL Inspector, where the attachments are listed, or just not show the size.

You would basically see in the attachments lists something like: filename.ext (5 KB), textfile.txt (1 M)

The Attachments method is ATTACH_BY_VALUE, so I know the size is coming from the  PR_ATTACH_SIZE and that is a calculated property based on the contents of PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN.

So Do you think there is a way to hide the (5 KB) text or to replace it with other value?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that unless you directly modify the RTF control that shows the file names.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, would that be possible to modify an Outlook control?

Comment: Using low level Windows API (FindWindow, etc.) It is certainly not documented or supported.

Comment: tried that option already, but unfortunately the control is encapsulated, not getting to much out of it, so normal ListView messages will not work at all, thanks anyway for your help.